# how can I block copy data column to column in DataGridPremium

Tags: javascript, material-ui, datagrid

I don't know, but I can't find a way to block copying data from column A to column B. Using an example with an image. Want to be able to copy data from Commodity column but only in this column. However, I don't want that data to be able to paste in the TraderName column.

In summary, I want to copy and paste data from column A only in column A, Copy and paste data from column B only in column B, etc....

[image]